# Import all sass file within directory with webpack

Tags: sass, webpack

I'm currently trying to use Webpack to bundle all my files and I don't know how to proceed when dealing with multiple folders and `.scss` files.

I used to use grunt to do these tasks, and this is an example of my folder structure:

```
functions
    - _mixin.scss
    - _function.scss
    - [...]
variables
    - _colors.scss
    - _typo.scss
    - [...]
ui
    - _button.scss
    - _grid.scss
    - [...]
view
    - _home.scss
    - _about.scss
    - [...]
```

With `Grunt` I would run a task to generate a file called `main.scss` containing all the `@import`, for example:

```
@import 'function/_mixin.scss';
@import 'function/_function.scss';
@import 'variables/_colors.scss';
@import 'variables/_typo.scss';
[...]
```

Currently I'm specifying an import inside my `.js` file (used in conjunction with `extract-text-webpack-plugin`) to define the `main.scss` file, but each new `import`, or old one, needs to be added/removed manually. Is there a way to automate this task with `WebPack`?

Comment: if you're importing scss files into the component js, the resulting css will be required on demand by the user (i.e. via loaders). IF you want to compile the scss as one file without importing them as components into webpack, then remove the `@import scss` statements and compile them separately via npm scripts or otherwise (grunt/node-sass etc)

Comment: @DenisTsoi I'm just importing the compiled css. What I meant to say is, for example, if I create a new file inside the folder `ui`, I need to manually add `@import 'ui/newfile'`; on the main.scss file. I used to do it automatically using `grunt sass-compile-imports`.

Comment: hmmm - i suppose that's a bit non-common practice (since it's assuming your workflow is ensuring styles are tied to the component js/html dependencies) - therefore adding all partials like that automatically might not be commonly supported.

there's nothing stopping you from say, using grunt to auto compile the scss and require that `main.scss` into the entry file.

Comment: you could use globbing and try that (there's also a node-sass-globbing package)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-globbing

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-glob-loader!!! - found it

Comment: @DenisTsoi Nice! That's it! Would you mind turning it into an answer? So i can accept it? But anyway, really thanks for your help!

Comment: will do - Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note - only works with `webpack 2` (requires update for webpack 3^)

You could use the plugin `import-glob-loader` [github](https://github.com/Aintaer/import-glob-loader) / [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-glob-loader)

It supports globbing with

```
@import "foo/**/*";
```

which outputs to

```
@import "foo/1.scss";
@import "foo/bar/2.scss";
@import "foo/bar/3.scss";
```

Comment: This is [not working in webpack 3+](https://github.com/Aintaer/import-glob-loader/issues/10)

Comment: lemme look at this later - haven't checked with updated webpack version

Comment: @PossessWithin - did this comment work?
https://github.com/Aintaer/import-glob-loader/issues/10#issuecomment-414574993

Comment: Isn't this a super crucial feature? :s

Answer (score 12):

When webpack 3 or 4

Use [node-sass-glob-importer](https://github.com/maoberlehner/node-sass-magic-importer/tree/master/packages/node-sass-glob-importer)

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const globImporter = require('node-sass-glob-importer');

    ...
    test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      "css-loader",
      {
        loader: "sass-loader",
        options: {
          sassOptions: {
            importer: globImporter()
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Use this way.

```
// Import all files inside the `scss` directory and subdirectories.
@import 'scss/**/*.scss';
@import 'scss/component-*';
```

Comment: Can you suggest instructions for using with Webpack 4? I see `unknown property 'importer'`.

Comment: I dug further and learned that passing it as `options { sassOptions: importer: globIOmporter() }` passes option validation, but still fails to resolve any glob imports.

Comment: doesn't work for me, webpack 4.46.0, I tried to modify this config: gist.github.com/jez500/4f4295778e386ddbc96c2377e3415fc3