# Webpack dev server - Concat CSS files into one file on file save

Tags: webpack, react-scripts, react-app-rewired

**The problem statement**

I have a requirement in a legacy React application which has multiple scss files in a particular directory. The CSS is not imported at the component level, the application uses gulp as a build system where it watches for file changes, spits out corresponding CSS files, merges them, finally injects a link tag into the index.html file(This step need not be in watch mode) and the page gets reloaded.

**What is needed**

We need to move this from the gulp configuration to using Webpack for the above-mentioned steps.

**What I have tried so far - What is working**

My initial thoughts were to (Since we are using react-scripts and react-app-rewired)

1. Use node-sass-chokidar to compile the sass files into CSS and write them into a specific directory.
2. Once this step is done, in the config-overrides.js, I have used a Webpack plugin called `webpack-concat-plugin`, to merge the files in a specific directory into a single file and writes it to the build folder.
3. The index.html has a link tag that points to the location of this file

The above steps are working in production mode.

**What I have tried so far - What is not working**

I am trying to implement the same in dev mode as well, but I am not able to figure out "How do I run the webpack-concat-plugin everytime node-sass-chokidar spits out css files(it is running in watch mode and runs whenever an scss file changes)". I tried creating a custom Webpack plugin and use the watch mode to tap in, but I not sure about the above-mentioned question. The webpack plugin looks like this.

```
const pluginName = 'ConcatCSSPlugin';
const ConcatPlugin = require('webpack-concat-plugin');

class ConcatCSSOnFileChangeWebpackPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.watchRun.tap(pluginName, compilation => {
      console.log('The webpack hook is running');
      /* How should I invoke the ConcatPlugin */
    });
  }
}

module.exports = ConcatCSSOnFileChangeWebpackPlugin;
```

The config-overrides.js looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: function override(config, env) {
    if (env === 'production') {
      config.plugins.push(new ConcatPlugin({
        outputPath: 'build/styles',
        fileName: 'style.css',
        injectType: 'none',
        filesToConcat: ['./dist/compiled-css/**.css'],
        attributes: {
            async: true
        }
      }), new TestPlugin());

      config.stats = {
        all: true
      }
    }
    return config;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [additionalData](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#additionaldata) option from [sass-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/) to create a pseudo root file which includes all your scss files. To make sure you append it only once, you may need to use something like this:

```
let appendedOnce = false;

const sassLoaderRule = {
  loader: 'sass-loader',
  options: {
    additionalData: function (content) {
      if (appendedOnce) return content;

      appendedOnce = true;

      return `
        @import 'fileOne.scss'; 
        @import 'fileTwo.scss'; 
        @import 'etc.scss';
      ` + content;
    }
  }
}
```

Additionally, if there are too many files to import, you can use [node-sass-glob-importer](https://github.com/maoberlehner/node-sass-magic-importer/tree/master/packages/node-sass-glob-importer) and instead write: `@import './**/*.scss';`.
Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56895555/5968600) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to invent the wheel.... utilize webpack’s power.

Create a `root.scss` file which will import (using sass import) all the relevant `scss` files.

Then import it from you app root js file (you will need to provide loaders for handling sass).

These steps will add your scss files into webpacks depend your tree, that means that in dev mode webpack will watch them an recompile whatever’s needed.

The second part is to use `html-webpack-plugin` for building & injecting static assets to it.

Comment: That is exactly the problem. In the current scenario, I won't be able to add a root scss file, due to how the existing system works.

Comment: Why not? what is the problem?

Comment: The problem in the current scenario is that, they are using grunt to 1. compile scss to css, 2. combine all the css files into one and write it to a certain directory with a certain name, 3. the index.html file contains a link tag to that particular file. And we cannot be changing that behavior now.

Comment: I’m confused, the I’ve suggested replaces the process that you’ve described. Without the need to import each css file in its component